# Maps API throws NullPointerException on animateTo() method

Tags: android, android-maps, android-maps-v2, android-debug

I'm getting a fatal exception when trying to animate the map to a certain GeoPoint - here is the Exception:

```
12-20 17:53:20.400: E/Crittercism(3523): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-20 17:53:20.400: E/Crittercism(3523): at com.amazon.geo.maps.MercatorProjection.latLongToWorldPixels(MercatorProjection.java:397)
12-20 17:53:20.400: E/Crittercism(3523): at com.amazon.geo.maps.MercatorProjection.toPixels(MercatorProjection.java:69)
12-20 17:53:20.400: E/Crittercism(3523): at com.amazon.geo.maps.MapView.animateTo_AmazonInternal(MapView.java:1801)
12-20 17:53:20.400: E/Crittercism(3523): at com.amazon.geo.maps.MapController.animateTo(MapController.java:46)
12-20 17:53:20.400: E/Crittercism(3523): at com.fatattitude.myapplication.MyMapActivity.moveMapToPoint(BusMapActivity.java:1564)
```

Here is my code. My log output also shows that the GeoPoint had values of **LatitudeE6= 51537141** and **LongitudeE6= -246271**

```
private void moveMapToPoint(GeoPoint gp, int zoomLevel) {
MapController mc = mapView.getController();

if (zoomLevel < 0)
zoomLevel = mapView.getZoomLevel();

mc.stopAnimation(true);
mc.setZoom(zoomLevel);

String strGeoPointInfo = String.format("Lat:%d, Lng:%d", gp.getLatitudeE6(), gp.getLongitudeE6() );
Log.i("GeoPoint-Info", "**moveMapToPoint: " + strTestOutput);

mc.animateTo(gp);
}
```

If I comment the line

```
//mc.stopAnimation(true);
```

I no longer get the exception.

Can anyone help me to understand why this exception has occurred?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app is likely to wait before the GPS Sensor is looking for the location.

```
mMyLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
                    mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocation);
        }});
```

Comment: So you mean I need to add mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocation); after calling MapController mc = mapView.getController();

Comment: The point is to animate to your geoPoint in the runOnFirstFix method, cause you are trying to get your location before the sensor got it.

Comment: Thank you. I will change it and try again.

Comment: If that is not working, I'll try to explain it in some other way, but I am sure that will work. :)